# OSX: Pick screen for notifications

Tags: macos, notifications

I recently hooked up 2 displays to my MacBook.
Now the notifications always show up on my right screen. This means that I have to turn my head and in addition move my mouse a considerable long way to click on a notification.

Is there a way to make the notifications show up on a different screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications appear on your primary display. The primary display is typically the one showing the menu bar; however, you can show the menu bar on every display.

To change your primary display:

- Open **System Preferences.app** > **Displays**
- Select the **Arrangement** tab
- Drag the **menu bar** to the desired display

[image: OS X 10.10 Displays in System Preferences]